# How do I make a signed apk with upload key?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I follow [Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) which states "To create an upload key for new apps, follow the instructions on [sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)."

I check here under section "Use google play App signing", which redirects me to [Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423). This link is the same as the first link so I stuck in a loop of redirects.

I check under section "Generate a key and keystore" in [sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) which again links me to [Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

If I check under section "Manually sign an APK" in [sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) I see note stating I should use my upload key if I wanted to sign with google play app signing and for more information I should check [Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

I have no idea where to get the upload key. I am just in a redirect loop.

Comment: did you mean keystore?

Comment: i want to sign apk, to do so i need to generate a key and keystore using upload key which i have no idea how to get and is never explained. i know how to make it without using upload key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An "upload key" isn't really anything special- it is just another key in a keystore. You need to register this key as an upload key in the developer console for Google to recognize it as your upload key.

To generate an upload key, simply follow the steps for generating a key and a keystor under "Generate a key and keystore" on the [Sign Your App documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html). The key you generate there will be your upload key.

Once you have your upload key generated, you need to export it using

```
keytool -export -rfc -keystore upload-keystore.jks -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem
```

where `upload-keystore.jks` is the name of the keystore containing the key you want to use as an upload key and `upload` is the alias of the key.

Finally, you need to go to your app in the developer console, go to Release Management > App signing, then click the "Upload Public Key Certificate" button to upload the `.pem` file you generated earlier. This registers your key an "upload key" for that app.

Comment: So what do I need to do with my just generated .jks file? I have uploaded my first release apk signed with this key to Console, after that I can get Upload certificate. What's next?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean for Google App Signing?
All process is same like before by creating your key from AndroidStudio, choose Build -> Generate Signed APK -> Create new -> Back -> Then follow the dialog process.

So where is the Google App Signing?
per the [Help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423), it's a security feature for developer if you lose your key.

> If you lose your keystore or think it may be compromised, Google Play App Signing makes it possible to request a reset to your upload key. If you're not enrolled in Google Play App Signing and lose your keystore, you'll need to publish a new app with a new package name.